# The opposide of string.find() in Lua

Tags: lua

The function `string.find(char)` returns the first occurrence of the pattern in `char`, but is there any way I can do the reverse: give the position as an int and return the character/number that is there and else returns `nil`.

I have searched for it if any function exists in the official libraries of the Lua programming language, no results.

I want to make a program which converts a formula of a substance(chemistry) like glucose for example, to the mass in units(u) it has, that is why I need a way to look what is next to the symbol and look if what lies next to the symbol, is a number.

Comment: you can find for `char..'(%d)'` and store the returned result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`string.sub`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-string.sub) function does what you want here.

> `string.sub (s, i [, j])`
>
> Returns the substring of `s` that starts at `i` and continues until `j`; `i` and `j` can be negative. If `j` is absent, then it is assumed to be equal to `-1` (which is the same as the string length). In particular, the call `string.sub(s,1,j)` returns a prefix of `s` with length `j`, and `string.sub(s, -i)` returns a suffix of `s` with length `i`.